# How do I add rows/columns to an existing xlsm file in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, spreadsheet, xlsm

I have an existing .xlsm file in my application. I have to be able to edit it. I mean I want to add rows/columns to it. How do I do it? What are the possible solutions? I have just started learning Rails, so I am unfamiliar with most of the things.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [rubyXL](https://github.com/weshatheleopard/rubyXL) gem. It lets you edit xslx files e.g. `worksheet[0][0].change_contents("", worksheet[0][0].formula)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will look into it.